# Creating a Pager in AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, pager

this [What is the cost difference between paging with a cursor or using offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291291/what-is-the-cost-difference-between-paging-with-a-cursor-or-using-offset) question lead me to the question, how do I actually build a Pager with Cursor/Offset/Limit in AppEngine (Python 2.7).

I know how to do that with MySQL and PHP easily => `LIMIT x,y`

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using cursors to do paging is a different approach to solving the problem than using queries with offsets. As Nick noted in the answer to the question that you linked, using offset incurs a possibly heavy expense of datastore operations. Cursors circumvent that cost, and they are the better solution to the problem.

Fortunately, this is a wheel that does not need to be reinvented. Ben Davies has created a [PagedQuery class](http://code.google.com/p/he3-appengine-lib/wiki/PagedQuery) that you can use directly in your AppEngine/Python code and it does virtually all of the work for you.

I use it in my blogging software, and I can't recommend it highly enough.