# How to pagination many entities in ndb [GAE / Python]

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to get a page in many entities.

the model is 10000 entities,
I want to get a index 5000.

```
entities = Model.query().fetch(10, offset=5000)
```

but, this is anti pattern.

use cursor pattern,

```
entities, cursor, more = Model.query().fetch_page(10) // 0〜10
entities, cursor, more = Model.query.fetch_page(10, start_cursor=cursor) // 10〜20
```

this is get a start cursor.

```
cursor = ??? // how to get a cursor start index 5000.
```

i want to get a cursor.
Is this a good Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think GAE support random access, that is why you need offset. I don't understand your question, you know the cursor pattern and it already returns the cursor. I think cursor is meant for paging, and offset is in general to skip some entities.

Comment: Yeah, but the "weird" thing with Offset is that IT STILL READS THE OFFSETTED DATA.  With how the datastore is built, you will end up "scanning" your offset before scanning your results... which means that you might have to pay more than you'd expect because of that offset

Comment: As I mentioned, offset is a general way. If your paging only next and prev should be okay to use the fetch page. I think in all databases if you do offset, it still scans your offset. It is just in GAE you get billed by it. Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291291/what-is-the-cost-difference-between-paging-with-a-cursor-or-using-offset

Comment: I wasn't saying that regarding your answer specifically, more as a warning to @kuninori. Obviously offset always scan.  But as you say, in GAE you pay for it.  I would indeed do paging and fetch if I was in the same problem :)

Comment: thanks, english is difficult. I read a this page [http://proppy-appstats.appspot.com/#12](http://proppy-appstats.appspot.com/#12) Offset pattern is costly performance and price. I want to `/?page=100`. if the cursor is cache on memcache, ok?